# Typesetting an empty square root

Tags: symbols

Is there a preferred way to typeset an empty `sqrt`? What I'm doing now is `\sqrt{\phantom{a}}`, are there other/preferred ways like a standalone symbol? Or should I just create a new macro with the phantom `a`?

Comment: I'd just use `\surd` unless you specifically need the top bar.

Comment: I didn't know about `\surd` When the sqrt is introduced in mathematical textbooks, how is the empty symbol printed? Is it ok to print it without the top bar?

Comment: Where the Chicago Manual of Style writes "The radical sign √ is used to denote the square root" I would type that in LaTeX as `The radical sign $\surd$ is used to denote the square root`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Ok, thanks, I'll check if it is also used in the local textbooks and if yes I'll follow your advice.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `\surd` command just produces the radical symbol √ as opposed to `\sqrt{stuff}` which typesets the square root of `stuff` with a bar over `stuff`. The Chicago Manual of Style uses just the radical symbol in the text "The radical sign √ is used to denote the square root".

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Compare:

\begin{itemize}
\item The radical sign $\surd$ is used to denote the square root.

\item The radical sign $\sqrt{}$ is used to denote the square root.

\item The radical sign $\sqrt{\phantom{x}}$ is used to denote the square root.
\end{itemize}

Alternatively: the square root of $x$ is denoted $\surd x$ or $\sqrt{x}$.

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of resulting document]

The Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics also just uses the radical sign (without an over bar) when defining both the terms "radical" and "square root".

Comment: Notice that `\surd` places the symbol a bit higher, hence producing more pleasant vertically centered output.

Comment: Let me add that the bar used in root notation historically was used as parentheses, before parentheses were introduced. So it is correct to write √(2  + 2) = 2.