# How to create a bracket-ing √-Operator?

Tags: spacing, amsmath, math-operators

In formulas involving square roots, I consider the overline rather irritating and would like to create an operator that turns `\sqrt{x}` into `√[x]`, i.e. the argument is bracket-delimited instead of the usual overlining. How can this be achieved?

So far, I tried

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\orgsqrt}{\sqrt}
\renewcommand{\sqrt}[2][]{\orgsqrt[#1]{}\left[#2\right]}
```

but the spacing is not very appealing:

[image: √ [x]]

Ideally, the end of the √-Symbol would directly connect to the ['s upper left corner.

Comment: Not an answer your question, but have you considered writing `(x)^{1/2}` instead?

Comment: What about `$\surd$`?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sure, but a √ is more distinctive to spot, and fractions in exponents don't look that nice either...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good point, [it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150064/430) does look better, though that unfortunately fails at the optional argument, i.e. cube roots and the like cannot be typeset that way

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29834/430

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Then use `\LetLtxMacro` too ;-)

Comment: If tight(er) spacing is a goal, don't use `\left` and `\right`, as they insert a bit of extra white space.

Comment: @Mico Good point. Ideally, the operator would be a pure `\DeclareMathOperator` without delimiters, but smart enough to connect (and resize) to [ or ( if that's what the argument starts with)...

Answer (score 5):

If you let the `\sq`rt grow large it might be hard to avoid a horizontal notch at the top, but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}}
\]

\newcommand\bsqrt[2][]{%
\sqrt[{#1}]{\vphantom{\left[#2\right]}}\left[#2\right]%
}


\[
\bsqrt{\frac{1}{\bsqrt{\frac{1}{\bsqrt{x}}}}}
\]

\newcommand\bbsqrt[2][]{%
\sqrt[{#1}]{\vphantom{\left[\vcenter{\hbox{$#2$}}\right]}}%
\left[\vcenter{\hbox{$#2$}}\right]%
}


\[
\bbsqrt{\frac{1}{\bbsqrt{\frac{1}{\bbsqrt{x}}}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 hm, looking at the big √s makes me thing by adding a line to the lower right corner would already make it look like a `[`, so [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29834/430) could basically be used to create a slightly different √ that is overlayed with a [...

Answer (score 4):

See EDIT at end of answer for support of sqrt index in `\displaystyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\sqrt#1{\stretchrel{\surd}{\left[#1\right]}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{x} \quad \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} \quad
\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro `\stretchrel` takes an optional integer argument indicating the maximum percent stretch allowed.  Any stretch beyond that value results in an increasing width, as well.  Thus defining `\sqrt` as

```
\def\sqrt#1{\stretchrel[200]{\surd}{\left[#1\right]}}
```

would result in the following depiction, in which the most stretched `\surd` is also widened:

[image]

If the gap between the surd and the bracket is considered too large, a negative space could be added:

```
\def\sqrt#1{\stretchrel{\surd}{\!\left[#1\right]}}
```

yielding

[image]

---

EDIT to support index on sqrt (but only in displaystyle).  The earlier solutions support math styles, as shown in the first two examples of this MWE.  Here, I introduce `\dsqrt` in the third example below, which supports indices on the sqrt; however it only functions in `\displaystyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\sqrt#1{\stretchrel{\surd}{\left[#1\right]}}
%%% THE FOLLOWING DISABLES MATH-MODE PRESERVATION OF scalerel, WHICH MAKES
%%% NESTED scalerel MACROS MUCH MORE EFFICIENT BY ELIMINATING NESTED \mathchoice
\makeatletter
\def\turnoffsavemode{%
  \edef\m@switch{T}\LMex=1ex\relax\LMpt=1pt\relax%
  \renewcommand\ThisStyle[1]{\ifmmode\def\@mmode{T}##1\else\def\@mmode{F}##1\fi}%
}
\makeatother
%%%
% \dsqrt only works in displaystyle, but supports sqrt index
\newcommand\dsqrt[2][]{\stackinset{l}{1.8pt}{c}{2.5pt}{\scriptscriptstyle#1}%
  {\turnoffsavemode\stretchrel{\surd}{\left[#2\right]}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{x} \quad \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} \quad
\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}}
\]
\[\scriptstyle
\sqrt{x} \quad \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} \quad
\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}}
\]
\[
\dsqrt[3]{x} \quad \dsqrt[3]{\frac{x}{y}} \quad
\dsqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\dsqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\dsqrt[3]{x}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, though it's too bad `\surd` cant do e.g. $\sqrt[3]{\ }$

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I have provided `\displaystyle` support for the feature.  See edit at end of answer.

Comment: NOTE TO READERS: The functionality of the `\turnoffsavemode` macro has been incorporated into the pre-existing `scalerel` macro named `\ignoremathstyle` as of version 1.7 of `scalerel` (FEBRUARY 2015).